# How can I prevent the initial assignment of property values from triggering an event in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a WPF project which has a main window containing a tab control which, in turn, contains several user controls.

I need the main window to display a warning when the value of certain properties have changed on the various user controls. I am using an event handler to populate a TextBlock when these properties change.

The remaining problem I have is that when the application is started, and the different UI properties get assigned an initial value, this assignment seems to be triggering the event. I  only want to display this warning when the user has changed something.

Here's what I have:

**An abstract class which facilitates the event**

```cs
public class ViewModelBase {
    Boolean isBusy;

    protected virtual void OnConfigurationChanged(EventArgs args) {
        EventHandler handler = ConfigurationChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    public event EventHandler ConfigurationChanged;
}
```

**User controls which trigger the event when applicable properties change**

```cs
class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    String myTextField;

    public MyTextField {
        get => myTextField;
        set {
            myTextField = value;
            OnConfigurationChanged(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**In my main window, I instantiate the user control and subscribe to the event. I also have the unsaved changes property in here**

```cs
class MainWindowVM : ViewModelBase {
    String unSavedChanges;

    public MainWindowVM() {
        MyViewModel MyVM = new MyViewModel();
        MyVM.ConfigurationChanged += onConfigurationChanged;
    }

    String UnsavedChanges {
        get => unSavedChanges;
        set {
            unSavedChanges = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UnsavedChanges));
        }
    }

    void onConfigurationChanged(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
        UnsavedChanges = "Configuration not saved.";
    }
}
```

**A XAML TextBlock bound to UnsavedChanges**

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UnsavedChanges}"
                           Foreground="Red"
                           Margin="10"/>
```

Comment: You can set the initial value using the private field instead the public property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this is obvious to most folks, but for anyone else that struggles with this issue:

- In order for an initial value to be reflected in a property-bound UI component, the value must be assigned to the underlying **field** in the object **constructor**. Changes to the field outside of the constructor will not be seen by the corresponding property and, in turn, will have no effect on the property-bound UI component.
- Assigning a value to a property which invokes `OnPropertyChanged()` on `set` will *always* trigger the subscribed event. The constructor is not exempt in this regard.